# SEARCHING SPECIAL CHARACTERS - SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, pattern-matching, special-characters

I'm receiving an error regarding the following syntax used for pattern matching:

```
'%[0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][.-][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][.-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

SQL SERVER 2008 does not like the [.-] portion.

What is the correct syntax when looking for only a period or a hyphen as the segment separator?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure to escape them. `[\.-]`

Comment: Where are you using this, a like clause?

Comment: @scsimon Yes, as part of a LIKE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to escape the hyphen...

```
WHERE SomeColumn LIKE '%[0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][.!-][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][.!-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' ESCAPE '!'
```